# Импорт переменной из другого файла

Tags: python, tkinter

Не получается присвоить значение переменной из другого файла. Чаще всего предлагали сделать переменную глобальной, но это не помогло. Найти решения не могу, подскажите пожалуйста что я сделал не так:

main:

```
from tkinter import *
import os
master = Tk()


def return_entry(en):
    global content
    content = entry.get()
    os.system('main1.py')


Label(master, text="Путь: ").grid(row=0, sticky=W)
entry = Entry(master)
entry.grid(row=0, column=1)


entry.bind('<Return>', return_entry)


mainloop()
```

main1:

```
import os, csv
from main import *

path = content
filelist = []
with open("files.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
      for file in files:
        filelist.append(os.path.join(file))
    for name in filelist:
        print(name,  file=f)
```

Ошибка:

> path = content NameError: name 'content' is not defined

Comment: идет вызов `content` до ее определения. В одном файле сначала все отладить надо.

Comment: чтобы сделать переменную глобальной нужно после/перед `master=Tk()` написать `content = None` (вместо `None` можно использовать любое другое значение)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mainloop` - это "бесконечный" цикл, работающий все время, пока существует окно. Получается, что код модуля `main1` начнет выполняться, только когда окно будет закрыто. Причем, код в `main1` начнет выполняться независимо от того, было ли что-то введено в текстовое поле или нет.

Но насколько я понимаю вашу задумку, запись в файл вам нужно выполнить после того, как нажата кнопка <kbd>Enter</kbd>, значит и вызывать запись нужно из обработчика этого события.

Просто перенесите запись в файл внутрь функции `return_entry`.

```
from tkinter import *
import os
master = Tk()


def return_entry(en):
    content = entry.get()
    
    path = content
    filelist = []
    with open("files.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for file in files:
                filelist.append(os.path.join(file))
        
        for name in filelist:
            print(name,  file=f)


Label(master, text="Путь: ").grid(row=0, sticky=W)
entry = Entry(master)
entry.grid(row=0, column=1)


entry.bind('<Return>', return_entry)


mainloop()
```

Если нужно разделить на несколько модулей, то вынесите запись в файл в отдельную функцию, импортируйте ее в модуле `main.py` и запускайте эту функцию из функции `return_entry`, при этом модуль `main.py` будет основным:

```
# main.py
from tkinter import *
from main1 import write_to_file


master = Tk()


def return_entry(en):
    content = entry.get()
    write_to_file(content)


Label(master, text="Путь: ").grid(row=0, sticky=W)
entry = Entry(master)
entry.grid(row=0, column=1)


entry.bind('<Return>', return_entry)


mainloop()
```

```
# main1.py
import os, csv


def write_to_file(content):
    path = content
    filelist = []
    with open("files.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for file in files:
                filelist.append(os.path.join(file))
        
        for name in filelist:
            print(name,  file=f)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Что-то сразу поспешил и не подумал о том, что нужно импортировать саму функцию, а не значение в нее)

Да, задумка в том, чтобы вписывать в строку путь к необходимым папкам и сканировать их составляющие, которые в последствии буду сравнивать между собой)